# Vue.js: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am learning Vue.js and I am processing to create simple project. When I click on edit button, the product that select before don't return back and when I try to select product, I got the error "Cannot read property'includes'of undefined". And Sorry, I'm new on Vue.js and also stack-overflow.

Here is my label to select product.

```html
<v-col cols="12">
    <label class="font-weight-bold">Select Product</label>
 <div>
  <v-autocomplete
  dense
  solo
  item-text="name"
  item-value="name"
  return-object
  :items="products"
  @input="addTocart"
  ></v-autocomplete>
 </div>
</v-col>
```

[image]

And Here is my code in Script.

```html
        fetchReturn() {
   this.$axios
   .$get(`api/return-purchase/` + this.$route.params.id)
   .then(res => {
    this.$set(this.$data, 'form', res.returnpurchase);
   
    // Initial value = pivot
    for (let i in this.form.items) {
     Vue.set(this.form.items[i], 'quantity', this.form.items[i].pivot.quantity);
     Vue.set(this.form.items[i], 'unit_price', this.form.items[i].pivot.unit_price);
     Vue.set(this.form.items[i], 'discount', this.form.items[i].pivot.discount);
    }
   })
   .catch(err => {
    console.log(res.response);
   });
  },
  addTocart(item) {
   if (this.form.items.include(item)) {
    alert("already there");
   } else {
    this.form.items.push(item);
   }
   Vue.set(item, 'quantity', 1);
   Vue.set(item, 'discount', 1);
  },
```

[image]

Full code.

```html
<template>
 <v-app>
  <v-card class="mx-5 my-5">
   <div class="teal darken-1">
    <v-card-title class="white--text">Edit​ Return Purchase</v-card-title>
   </div>
   <v-divider></v-divider>
   <div class="px-5">
    <p class="caption font-italic pt-5">The field labels marked with * are required input fields.</p>
    <v-row>
     <v-col md="6" cols="12">
      <label for="reference_no" class="font-weight-bold">Reference No</label>
      <v-text-field 
       solo 
       outlined 
       dense 
       v-model="form.reference_no"
      ></v-text-field>
     </v-col>
     <v-col md="6" cols="12">
      <label class="font-weight-bold">Location*</label>
      <v-autocomplete
       item-value="address"
       item-text="address"
       solo
       outlined
       dense
       label="Business Location"
       return-object
       v-model="form.branch"
       :items="locations"
      ></v-autocomplete>
     </v-col>
     <v-col md="6" cols="12">
      <label class="font-weight-bold">Supplier</label>
      <v-autocomplete
       :items="suppliers"
       item-text="name"
       item-value="name"
       solo
       outlined
       dense
       return-object
       v-model="form.supplier"
       label="Please select Supplier"
      ></v-autocomplete>
     </v-col>
     <v-col md="6" cols="12">
      <label class="font-weight-bold">Account</label>
      <v-autocomplete
       :items="accounts"
       item-text="name"
       item-value="name"
       solo
       outlined
       dense
       return-object
       v-model="form.account"
       label="Please select Account"
      ></v-autocomplete>
     </v-col>
     
     <v-col cols="12">
      <label class="font-weight-bold">Select Product</label>
      <div>
       <v-autocomplete
        dense
        solo
        item-text="name"
        item-value="name"
        return-object
        :items="products"
        @input="addTocart"
       ></v-autocomplete>
      </div>
     </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <div>
     <label class="font-weight-bold mb-3">Product Table</label>
     <table class="tableReturn">
      <thead>
       <tr class="tableReturn--header">
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Code</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Unit Price</td>
        <td>Discount</td>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>Actions</td>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr class="tableReturn--td" v-for="(item, index) in form.items" :key="index">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.code}}</td>
        <td>
         <input type="number" class="table-quantity" v-model="form.items[index].quantity" />
        </td>
        <td>
         <input
          type="number"
          class="table-quantity"
          v-model="form.items[index].unit_price"
          placeholder="0.00"
         />
        </td>
        <td>
         <input
          type="number"
          class="table-quantity"
          v-model="form.items[index].discount"
          placeholder="0.00"
         />
        </td>
        <td>USD {{ discountedPrice(item) | formatMoney }}</td>
        <td>
         <v-btn small color="red" outlined @click="removeItem(index)">
          <v-icon>mdi-delete</v-icon>
         </v-btn>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="py-5" colspan="2">Total</td>
        <td colspan="3">{{ Qty }}</td>
        <td>USD {{ Total | formatMoney }}</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>

    <v-row>
     <v-col md="6" cols="12">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column mb-5">
       <label for="" class="font-weight-bold">Return Note</label>
       <textarea cols="30" rows="7" class="textarea" v-model="form.return_des"></textarea>
      </div>
     </v-col>
     <v-col md="6" cols="12">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column mb-5">
       <label for="" class="font-weight-bold">Staff Note</label>
       <textarea cols="30" rows="7" class="textarea" v-model="form.staff_des"></textarea>
      </div>
     </v-col>
    </v-row>
   </div>
   <v-btn
    @click.prevent="updateReturn"
    class="blue mx-5 darken-2 mb-5 grey--text text--lighten-4"
   >
    <v-icon>mdi-check</v-icon>Update
   </v-btn>
  </v-card>
 </v-app>
</template>

<script>
 import Vue from "vue";

 let numeral = require('numeral');

 Vue.filter('formatMoney', function(value) {
  return numeral(value).format('00,00.00')
 });

 export default {

  name: "editReturn",

  created(){

   this.fetchReturn();
   this.fetchLocation();
   this.fetchSupplier();
   this.fetchAccount();
   this.fetchProduct();
   
  },

  data(){
   return {
    form: {
     items: []
    },
    suppliers: [],
    locations: [],
    products: [],
    returnpurchase: [],
    accounts: []
   };
  },

  computed: {
   Qty() {
    if (this.form.hasOwnProperty("items")) {
     return this.form.items.reduce((total, item) => {
     return total + Number(item.quantity);
     }, 0);
    }
   },

   Total() {
    if (this.form.hasOwnProperty("items")) {
     return this.form.items.reduce((total, item) => {
     let subtotal =
      (item.unit_price - (item.unit_price * item.discount) / 100) *
      item.quantity;
     return total + subtotal;
     }, 0);
    }
   } 
  },

  methods: {
   discountedPrice(product) {
    return (
     (product.unit_price -
      (product.unit_price * product.discount) / 100) *
     product.quantity
    );
   },

   fetchLocation() {
    this.$axios.$get(`api/location`)
    .then(res => {
     this.locations = res.locations.data;
     // this.$set(this.$data, "locations", res.locations.data);
     console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
     console.log(err.response);
    });
   },

   fetchSupplier() {
    this.$axios.$get(`api/supplier`)
    .then(res => {
     this.suppliers = res.suppliers.data;
     // this.$set(this.$data, "suppliers", res.suppliers.data);
     console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
     console.log(err.response);
    });
   },

   fetchAccount(){
    this.$axios.$get(`api/account`)
    .then(res =>{
     this.accounts = res.account;
     console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(err => {
     console.log(err.response);
    });
   },

   fetchProduct() {
    this.$axios
    .$get(`/api/product`)
    .then(res => {
     this.products = res.products.data;
     // this.$set(this.$data, "items", res.items.data);
     console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
     console.log(err);
    });
   },

   fetchReturn() {
    this.$axios
    .$get(`api/return-purchase/` + this.$route.params.id)
    .then(res => {
     this.$set(this.$data, 'form', res.returnpurchase);

     // Initial value = pivot
     for (let i in this.form.items) {
      Vue.set(this.form.items[i], 'quantity', this.form.items[i].pivot.quantity);
      Vue.set(this.form.items[i], 'unit_price', this.form.items[i].pivot.unit_price);
      Vue.set(this.form.items[i], 'discount', this.form.items[i].pivot.discount);
     }
    })
    .catch(err => {
     console.log(res.response);
    });
   },
   addTocart(item) {
    if (this.form.items.includes(item)) {
     alert("already there");
    } else {
     this.form.items.push(item);
    }
    Vue.set(item, 'quantity', 1);
    Vue.set(item, 'discount', 1);
   },

   updateReturn() {
    this.$axios.$patch(`api/return-purchase/` + this.form.id, {

     branch: this.form.branch,
     products: this.form.products,
     supplier: this.form.supplier,
     account: this.form.account,
     return_des: this.form.return_des,
     staff_des: this.form.staff_des,
     
    })
    .then(res => {
     this.returnpurchase = res.data;
     // this.$set(this.$data, "returnpurchase", res.data);
     this.$set(this.$data, "returnpurchase" , res.returnpurchase);
     this.$router.push(`/return/return-purchase/view`);
     console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
     console.log(err.response);
    });
   },
   removeItem(index) {
    this.form.items.splice(index, 1);
   }
  }
 };
</script>

<style lang="scss">
 .textarea {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  outline: 1px solid #461577;
 }

 .tableReturn {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  &--header {
   font-weight: 500;
   text-align: left;
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  }

  &--td {
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  }
 }

 .table-quantity {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: how do you set your data? `form.items`

Comment: @Ahmad Mobaraki What's you mean?

Comment: Can you add `console.log(this.form.items)` to your `addTocart(item)` method?

Comment: @webprogrammer I added already, but it still error.

Comment: @adding `console.log(this.form.items)` don't fix the issue. Can you show me output of that function?

Comment: I am talking about browser console.

Comment: @webprogrammer Ok Thank you so much, now i fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not property like include in array/list it should be `includes`. Small typo.

```js
addTocart(item) {
  if (this.form.items.includes(item)) { // <-- change include to includes 
    alert("already there");
  } else {
    this.form.items.push(item);
  }
  Vue.set(item, 'quantity', 1);
  Vue.set(item, 'discount', 1);
},
```

**Update**

If `res.returnpurchase` is undefined then it is setting whole form variable as undefined or if items in undefined then it is setting items as undefined which should be `[]` for using includes. Add check for this,

```js
if (res.returnpurchase == undefined 
   || res.returnpurchase.items == undefined) {
   this.form.items = []
}
```

Comment: Here is my error alert.                                                                                                                    TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
    at VueComponent.addTocart (edit.vue?f0c5:293)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854)
    at VueComponent.invoker (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854)

Comment: I tried similar code but not getting any error. I am suspicious about your fetchReturn() function. If `res.returnpurchase` is undefined then it is setting whole form variable as undefined or if items in undefined then it is setting items as undefined which should be [] for using includes. Add check for this, `if (res.returnpurchase == undefined || res.returnpurchase.items == undefined) this.form.items = []`

Comment: Welcome, I updated the answer. If you issue solved than mark this as correct answer.